# Unwrap text for concatenation

Tags: concatenation, psql, pgadmin, unwrap

Some cells in my output contain wrapped text, presumably because the text was wrapped inside these cells in Excel and then the table was imported on the Postrgresql DB. Now I'm querying this table, and I can only see the topmost row of the wrapped text. It is a problem especially if I want to use this text in a concatenation. How can I unwrap a text in my SELECT statement?